# How to convert ascii to char in NDK?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to use convert ASCII to Char in Android NDK but it gives me Fatal error for segement and my app force stops.
Code:

```
value = "116";
char word = atoi(value);
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, word);
```

Error:

```
 Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000074
```

Comment: `NewStringUTF` requires `word` to be a pointer to `char`,  not a `char`. I'm surpeised that this compiles. What happens is this: You parse a string and then pass the parsed number to `NewStringUTF` as if it were a pointer. Which it isn't - bang! Perhaps you should omit the intermediary step of parsing anf just pass `value` to ´NewStringUTF`?

Comment: can you plz tell me how to correct above code.

Comment: Throw out the `word` and `return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, value);` That will give you a string that has `"116"` as its value. (Okay, that's not waht you want, see the answer. I've misread your question, sorry.)

Comment: This makes very little sense unless "116" is a stand-in for a string that varies at runtime.  Otherwise you might as well just assign a numeric value or even use it to initialize a string.

Comment: You are trusting that the string input to `atoi` will return 0...127. Depending on where you get it from, you might want to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `NewStringUTF()` a c-string (i.e. an array of `char` with an ending null):

```
value = "116";
char word[2];
word[0] = atoi(value);  // first char converted as you want
word[1] = 0;            // null termination (aka '\0')              
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, word);
```

Comment: Nitpicking: It should be either `NUL` or null. "*nul*" I'd consider a typo.